# Адаптивное размещение картинки

Tags: css3, html5

У меня есть изображение: 
[image: corenr]

На моем макете правая часть этого изображения на больших разрешениях развернута на всю ширину, но на десктопе и мобильных изображение должно сужаться, и правая часть скрывается. Пытаюсь это сделать так:

```
footer-img-block {
overflow-x: hidden;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100%;
max-width: 1041px;
height: 331px;
}
.footer-image {
background: url(/wp-content/themes/toster/images/palette.png) no-repeat;
height: 331px;
max-width: 1041px;
width: 100%;
z-index: 17;
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease;
transition: all .5s ease;
left: calc(100% - 500px);
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

}

Но при уменьшении разрешения, появляется горизонтальный скролл. Как можно разместить картинку так, чтобы скролл не появлялся и задняя часть изображения пряталась за пределами?

Comment: Изображение чем-то обёрнуто? Если да, то поможет overflow:hidden для блока, который регулирует ширину. Если нет - то это надо обрезать глобальные теги, вроде html или body, но это может привести к большим проблемам при использовании скриптов.

Comment: @vordzer, добавил к body overflow-x: hidden, скролл ушел, но я не рискну относить такое решение к адаптивным.

Comment: адаптивность в принципе подразумевает наличие всего контента в просматриваемой области. Если есть желание скрывать часть изображения - что-то должно его прятать. Это может быть обёртка самого изображения или обёртка более глобальная. Как альтернатива - использование изображения в качестве фонового, для него такое поведение естественно. Но также потребуется введение блока, для позиционирования фонового изображения.

Comment: Чтобы разобраться в чем проблема, добавьте в ваш вопрос [mcve]

Comment: @vordzer, как альтернатива использование фонового изображения - может ли это подразумевать отказ от ovefllow:hidden ? потому что на самом деле, не хотелось бы его применять.

Comment: Да, при фоновом изображении не понадобится overflow:hidden. Изображение, прикреплённое с помощью background-image автоматически будет обрезаться по ширине блока. Соответственно, достаточно проконтролировать размер этого блока.

Comment: @vordzer, окей, спасибо за совет! он мне помог. а можете еще подсказать касательно правильного расположения? у меня сейчас блок с оберткой наезжает на близстоящие блоки в футере. думаю, что неправильно задал position. свой вопрос дополнил.

Comment: Для решения вопроса с накладками надо следовать комментарию Cheg. Без внятного и полноценного примера не разобраться уже.